# How to connect postgresql with LDAP user?

Tags: linux, ldap, postgresql, database, openldap

I have a server with postgresql-9.4 fresh install and I have another server with LDAP already installed. I want to connect postgresql with LDAP user that already exists.

What's the basic configuration that I should change in /var/lib/pgsql/9.4/data/pg_hba.conf and what else I should do?

Answer (score 6):

Thanks everyone, I just made a change in /var/lib/pgsql/9.4/data/pg_hba.conf with :

```
local   all         all                               ldap ldapserver=ldap.server ldapport=389 ldaptls=0 ldapprefix="uid=" ldapsuffix=",ou=People,dc=domain,dc=com"
```

And the authentication works!

Comment: this worked for me: `ldapprefx="cn=" ldapsuffix=",cn=Users,dc=example,dc=com"`

Comment: do you need to create users first in the database?

Answer (score 3):

1. Read the Friendly Manual:

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/auth-methods.html

2. You probably want to use https://github.com/larskanis/pg-ldap-sync to sync your LDAP users and groups to PostgreSQL